# TableColumn setPreferredWidth shrink other column

Tags: java, swing

I wanted to fit the size of each columns with specified value in my `JTable`. But when I'm increasing the `setPrefferedWidth` for the other column it became shrink? I don't want to use `setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);` Any methods to solve this issue?

```
TableColumn column = null;

    for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        column = tbl.getColumnModel().getColumn(i);

        if(i == 0 || i == 1)
        {
            column.setPreferredWidth(100);
        }
        else if(i == 2 || i == 3 || i == 4)
        {
            column.setPreferredWidth(80);
        }
        else if(i == 5 || i == 6)
        {
            column.setPreferredWidth(250);
        }
        else
        {
            column.setPreferredWidth(150);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You'll want to take a look at [`JTable#setAutoResizeMode`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setAutoResizeMode-int-)

Comment: @MadProgrammer This works perfectly but how can I fit all the column in my JPanel?

Comment: You're making compromises between the available space the space you want to use, at some point, one or the other will conflict. The first thing you should do is make sure the table is contained within a `JScrollPane` and basically, not care.  Either you can to deal with one of the other auto resize modes, but one or more of the columns will suffer for it, or, size them to your needs and allow it to over/underflow

Comment: @Francisunoxx, `I don't want to use setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);` - why? This will display all the columns at there preferred size. If not enough space is available, then a scrollbar will appear.